# Initiallizing Values of ArrayList<Integer> with zeroes - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList array with a specified max capacity M and I want to initialize that array by filling it with zero values. Therefore I use the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

    array.add(i, 0);

}
```

However, this does not work. I get an indexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Indeed, I printed the array after that loop in order to test if it is filled with values but the result is an empty array: [].

Clearly, there is some important concept that I don't know. I am sure that the solution is simple but I miss some fundamental insight of the concept.

Comment: For an `ArrayList`, there is a difference between its *capacity* and its *size*. You should go through the doc to find that out.

Comment: Change the second line to: `array.add(0);`

Comment: What is the argument type of the arraylist ? Show its declaration.
In your case if it consists of Integers then it should be as follows:
List<Integer> array= new ArrayList<Integer>();

The for loop will remain the same.
You can also add directly by
 array.add(0);

Comment: @Rohit         Do you mean that when using array.size() I am talking about the current size instead of the max size of the array (i.e. its capacity)?

Comment: @Crusaderpyro  The declaration is as follows: List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(M);

Comment: @Kotsos Yes. `array.size()` is the current size, not the capacity. Moreover, the capacity isn't exactly a "max size", if you try to go over it, it will be increased.

Comment: @alfasin       This will add a zero at the end of the array. The thing is that I have to do that M times, since I want to fill in the array with zeroes. Therefore, shouldn't I have the for loop variable "i" as an index variable in the add method?

Comment: @Kotsos `add` without an index adds a new element to the end of the array. In your case, that's the same thing as using the index as you did.

Comment: @RohitJain     Yes, you are right. That was the problem: missuse of current cache size instead of "capacity". Thank you!

Comment: @trutheality   Thank you, that was the problem, i.e. using current size instead of "capacity". By the way, what you mean that "capacity" is not actually a max size and that the array can grow bigger than that? I have read somewhere that it is good to specify the max size of an arraylist, if it is known beforehand, in order to avoid overcoming that size, which internally means that a copy of the array will be created which in turn means slower performance and greater storage space demands.

Comment: @Kotsos Internally, the `ArrayList` stores a regular array of objects (`Object[]`). The size of that array is the current capacity. If you try to add more elements to the `ArrayList`, it will allocate a new object array of double that capacity (that's when you take a storage space hit) and then copy the elements from the old array to the new array (that's the performance hit), and then the capacity becomes the size of the new internal array (capacity increases). If you know ahead of time how many objects you'll have, you can specify the right initial capacity to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @trutheality   OK, that's what I had in mind too! Thank's for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `array.add(i, 0)` to `array.add(0);`.

You cannot add to those specified indices unless the size of the `ArrayList` is larger or equal since those indices don't exist.

Also you'll have to change your `for` loop as well since its size is not 100; it is 0. This is because when you declare `array = new ArrayList<Integer>(100)`, you're only specifying how much memory should be reserved for it - not its size. Its size is still 0 and will grow only when you add elements.

Comment: Always Remember indexOutOfBoundsException indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

Comment: @Trust         Yes, that's exactly what I did not understand when asking this question. Thank you very much for your helpfull reply!

Answer (score 11):

To initialize an ArrayList with 100 zeros you do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also make the list to 0 values by this code, after initializing the arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    list.add(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did actually after the comments of the colleagues! Thanks!